# Naming convention question, appropriate on this site?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170646/naming-conventions-for-new-apis-carpool-platform) question here? It was closed on stackoverflow.com as being off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. This is a site for questions about user experience, so your question would fit if it were along the lines of "which is easier to understand?", but the question as it stands is "what is your feedback as a developer". So you'd need to rewrite it to be about the usability of the API if you want us to accept it.

The fact is that usability of an API is kind of a gray area. You end up touching on information design, programming, UI design, and basic writing. No SE site that covers those topics really exists.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase it to shorter. I think I dont need to give so much context. I do want to try to get some feedback.

Comment: I think API usability is on-topic, but agree about needing to rewrite.

Comment: thanks you have been  most helpful.

Comment: I agree with @MonicaCellio.  API usability is "UX with a very specific product and a very specific user-group".  On-topic.  Whether this site has broad enough competence to answer such a question is another discussion.  UX is still UX...

Comment: I don't know how many of us there are, but APIs are my area. :-)

Comment: ...and it just got migrated to Programmers. :-(