# Are questions about UX naming-conventions and terminology on-topic?

Tags: support, questions

I often find myself looking for the names of design patterns and UI components.

Is it an on-topic question to describe what I am looking for, then ask for the name of it?

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

-- Phil Karlton

[This question/answer set](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/naming-convention-question-appropriate-on-this-site) seems to say “no,” but it appears to be in reference to a question about APIs which is not on topic for UX.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's even a tag for it: [terminology](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

The only caveat I would put is questions should be more "What is the industry standard term for this thingy" not "Let's come up with a good name for this thingy". The first solicits answers, the latter opinions.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point to look for tags...What about questions that solicit comparisons between similar terms?